# INNER JOINs with where on the joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Let's say we have

`SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON [....]`

Assuming `A` has 2 rows and `B` contains 1M rows including 2 rows linked to `A`:
`B` will be scanned only once with "actual # of rows" of 2 right?

If I add a `WHERE` on table `B`:

`SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON [....] WHERE B.Xyz > 10`

The `WHERE` will actually be executed before the join... So if the where
returns 1000 rows, the "actual # of rows" of `B` will be 1000...
I don't get it.. shouldn't it be <= 2???

What am I missing... why does the optimiser proceeds that way?
(SQL 2008)

Thanks

Comment: I think it's because table A contains more rows than B.. is it possible? I did not mentionned that A has a lot of row and I do a WHERE on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer will proceed whichever way it thinks is faster.  That means if the Xyz column is indexed but the join column is not, it will likely do the xyz filter first.  Or if your statistics are bad so it doesn't know that the join filter would pare B down to just two rows, it would do the WHERE clause first.

Answer (score 1):

It's based entirely on what indexes are available for the optimizer to use. Also, there is no reason to believe that the db engine will execute the WHERE before another part of the query. The query optimizer is free to execute the query in any order it likes as long as the correct results are returned. Again, the way to properly optimize this type of query is with strategically placed indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The "scanned only once" is a bit misleading.  A table scan is a horrendously expensive thing in SQL Server.  At least up to SS2005, a table scan requires a read of all rows into a temporary table, then a read of the temporary table to find rows matching the join condition.  So in the worst case, your query will read *and write* 1M rows, then try to match 2 rows to 1M rows, then delete the temporary table (that last bit is probably the cheapest part of the query).  So if there are no usable indexes on B, you're just in a bad place.

In your second example, if B.Xyz is not indexed, the full table scan happens *and* there's a secondary match from 2 rows to 1000 rows - even less efficient.  If B.Xyz *is* indexed, there should be an index lookup and a 2:1000 match - much faster & more efficient.

'course, this assumes the table stats are relatively current and no options are in effect that change how the optimizer works.

**EDIT:** is it possible for you to "unroll" the A rows and use them as a static condition in a no-JOIN query on B?  We've used this in a couple of places in our application where we're joining small tables (<100 rows) to large (> 100M rows) ones to great effect.